# Change text color of the active and non-active NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I would like to change the text color to "red" when the NSTextField becomes active.  All non-active text fields need to have "black" text.

Using the becomeFirstResponder method, I am able to change the text color to "red".  However, when the text field looses focus, the text color remains "red".  I need to the text color to change back to "black" once it is the non-active NSTextField.  I tried the resignFirstResponder method but it doesn't change the text color back to "black".

Here's my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyTextField : NSTextField {
}

@end
```

and

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    if (![super becomeFirstResponder]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        [self setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    if (![super resignFirstResponder]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        [self setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the field editor is taking the color attribute when the text field becomes first responder but it replaces it when the text field resigns. You'll most likely want to change the attributes on the field editor directly.

You can do this by substituting your own field editor in the window's delegate like so:

```
- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)client {

    if ([client isKindOfClass:[MyTextField class]]) {

        static NSTextView *fieldEditor;

        if (nil == fieldEditor) {
            fieldEditor = [[NSTextView alloc] init];
            [fieldEditor setFieldEditor:YES];      
        }

        [fieldEditor setDelegate:client]; 
        [fieldEditor setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];

        return fieldEditor;

    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: So I tried to put the -(id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor code in my AppDelegate.m but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to make the AppDelegate the window's delegate by connecting them in the xib editor.

Comment: Do you mean drag from the NSTextField to the AppDelegate and select "delegate"?  If so, I already tried that.  Or do you mean drag from the "window" icon in the dock to the "AppDelegate" icon and select "delegate"?

Comment: Ok I got it working sort of.  I had to add #import"MyTextField.h" into the AppDelegate.m file.  When I click a text box it does indeed make the text color red and changes back to black when the box is not active.  However, there's a weird problem with the first text box.  When I enter a number it is input into the last text box! I am using NSTextFields with Number Formatter.

Comment: When I run the program, whatever text field is the first responder (first one active), is the one that is acting weird.  For example, if I input a number into that field then I have to hit the "Tab" key twice until the next text field is selected. Upon the first "Tab" key press, the input will show up in the next text box.

Comment: The above code is working fine in my demo app. Something else must be wrong in your project.

Comment: Ok I deleted the `[fieldEditor setDelegate:client]` and everything works fine now. No weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't just add the method `-textDidEndEditing` in your `NSTextField` Subclass?

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
}
```